# Firestore documentReference.set() addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener not firing

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two model objects of the same type, user and institution.
The user object gets its uid from the Firebase.Auth user.
The institution gets its uid by creating a doucmentReference first then setting the object with the document reference uid.

I get a reference uid for both

The user object fires the addOnSuccessListener just fine.
The institution object does not fire either addOnSuccessListener or addOnFailureListener

Both objects only uses Firebase supported data types.

Here is the insert method and object classes:

```
public Observable<QueryResult> insert(Fetchable fetchable) {

        Query query = new Query.QueryBuilder().insert(fetchable).build();

        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            CollectionReference collectionReference = getCollectionReference(fetchable);
            DocumentReference documentReference;
            if(fetchable.getType() == Fetchable.Type.USER){
                //USER type uses User UID from FireBase Authentication
                documentReference = collectionReference.document(fetchable.getRemoteId());
            }else{
                documentReference = collectionReference.document();
                String id = documentReference.getId();
                fetchable.setRemoteId(id);
            }
            Timber.d(documentReference.getPath());
            documentReference.set(fetchable).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult(query, fetchable);
                Timber.d(queryResult.toString());
                emitter.onNext(queryResult);
                emitter.onComplete();
            }).addOnFailureListener(e ->{
                QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult(query, e);
                Timber.d(queryResult.toString());
                emitter.onNext(queryResult);
                emitter.onComplete();
            });
        });

public final class Institution implements Fetchable {


    public static final String KEY = "institution";
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int localId;
    private String remoteId;
    private String name;
    private String postalCode;
    private List<String> instructionProviderIds;
    private List<String> adminIds;
    private String creationDate;
    private String lastUpdate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    private List<String> accessList;

    @Ignore
    private final Fetchable.Type type = Type.INSTITUTION;

    @Ignore
    private Institution() {
        instructionProviderIds = new ArrayList<>();
        adminIds = new ArrayList<>();
        accessList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Institution(int localId, String remoteId, String name, String postalCode, List<String> instructionProviderIds, List<String> adminIds, String creationDate, String lastUpdate, String createdBy, String lastUpdatedBy, List<String> accessList) {
        this.localId = localId;
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
        this.name = name;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.instructionProviderIds = instructionProviderIds;
        this.adminIds = adminIds;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
        this.accessList = accessList;
    }

    public int getLocalId() {
        return localId;
    }

    public String getRemoteId() {
        return remoteId;
    }

    public void setRemoteId(String remoteId) {
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getCreatedOnDate() {
        return DateConverter.stringToDate(creationDate);
    }

    @Override
    public Date getLastUpdateOnDate() {
        return DateConverter.stringToDate(lastUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getAccessList() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void grantAccess(User user) {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public List<String> getInstructionProviderIds() {
        return instructionProviderIds;
    }

    public List<String> getAdminIds() {
        return adminIds;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

 public final class User implements Fetchable {

    public static final String KEY = "user";

    private String remoteId;
    private String email;
    private String displayName;
    private String creationDate;
    private String lastUpdate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    private List<String> accessList;
    @Ignore
    private final Fetchable.Type type = Type.USER;

    private User() {
        accessList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public User(String remoteId, String email, String displayName, String creationDate, String lastUpdate, String createdBy, String lastUpdatedBy, List<String> accessList) {
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
        this.email = email;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
        this.accessList = accessList;
    }

    public static String getID() {
        return KEY;
    }


    public String getRemoteId() {
        return remoteId;
    }

    public void setRemoteId(String remoteId) {
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getCreatedOnDate() {
        return DateConverter.stringToDate(creationDate);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }


    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }


    @Override
    public Date getLastUpdateOnDate() {
        return DateConverter.stringToDate(lastUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getAccessList() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void grantAccess(User user) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Not all fields from institution had getters.